# Select from Oracle Function

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Select From Oracle Function

I have a function that return an oracle table of object type.

When I run the function it runs successfully but I need to output its data and so for that I use the code `select * from table(my_func_name);` however this is coming through with an error that says table or view does not exists.

So I would like to get assistance as to why could this be happening

```
select * from table(my_func_name);
```

I want to get results as a table.

Comment: share the function code

Comment: It works, [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d31b84a13ad3148b91055167990c6276) is a dbfiddle demo of selecting from normal and pipelined function. Without more details we can't do much, I'm afraid.